# Add "My calendar" to a landing page to SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Our ui guys created a sketch of a new portal, and they contain a few dynamic web parts like "my calendar" and "my recent documents". The first one should show the upcoming events for the current user, and the latter is the same as the one on the default O365 start page. How can I add these to a new site? 
For the calendar, I found [this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamics101trainingcentercrm/archive/2013/06/04/how-to-add-a-calendar-web-part-on-sharepoint-online) but I don't see the calendar app in the list and I am not sure that this is even the good app to start.
Is there an out-of-the-box solution to present these "my ..." things? To me this looks like reusing objects that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a Calendar list and create a view inside this list which will show events of logged in user or may be based on other conditions.

You can then add this to your homepage using edit webpart. You will find all these lists in `Apps` section of edit web part

Comment: Does this mean that I need to maintain all events in this new list too? I would like to present the events that reside in the user's exchange online calendar.

Comment: you cant have exchange calendar in sharepoint but vice versa is possible. You can copy all existing events from outlook to sharepoint though